# Could you explain why this does not work?

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to make a function that takes the potatoes you have and gives you a farmer in return. I made it with a simple function but now when I want to add something I'm just copying pasting the same code. So I tried to make one function that does it all.

I don't want jQuery answers, please. I don't really get how that works just yet.

This is the HTML that calls that function:

`<button onClick="buy(autoFarmer, defaultAutoFarmerPrice, potatoes)" id="buyautofarmer">Buy Auto Farmer</button>`

This is the JavaScript:

```
var potatoes = 0,
    autoFarmer = 0,
    defaultAutoFarmerPrice = 17;

function buy(obj, price, potatoes) {
    if (potatoes > price) {
        obj++;
        console.log(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you look at console output? Please explain "doesn't work" better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Js primitives are passed by  value. Therefore increasing *obj* increases *obj* but not *autoFarmer* . A possible solution would be using objects:

```
var potatoes = {value:0},
autoFarmer ={value: 0,price:17};

function buy(obj, potatoes) {
  if (potatoes.value > obj.price) {
    obj.value++;
    console.log(obj.value);
  }
}

buy(autoFarmer,potatoes);
```

Comment: Sorry, it took so long to make this an answered question! This actually worked, I changed all the vars to objects to make it easier down the line. Thanks for suggesting this!

Answer (score 0):

Your code works as expected, there are no errors. You are sending potatoes as 0, and price is 17.
Console log will write in output only if `potatoes > price`, which is not the case now.

Answer (score 0):

The code works.. Just set potatoes larger than the price and the alert will fire

```js
var potatoes = 18,
    autoFarmer = 0,
    defaultAutoFarmerPrice = 17;

function buy(obj, price, potatoes) {
    if (potatoes > price) {
        obj++;
        alert(obj);
    }
}
```

```html
<button onClick="buy(autoFarmer, defaultAutoFarmerPrice, potatoes)" id="buyautofarmer">Buy Auto Farmer</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the output of your code

https://plnkr.co/edit/9UuhG5q82OvVlrOG2UXw?p=preview

```
var potatoes = 0, 
    autoFarmer = 0, 
    defaultAutoFarmerPrice = 17;

function buy(obj, price, potatoes) {
    document.querySelector('#output').value += '\nobj = ' + obj;
    document.querySelector('#output').value += '\nprice = ' + price;
    document.querySelector('#output').value += '\npotatoes = ' + potatoes;

    if (potatoes > price) {
        obj++;
        console.log(obj);
        document.querySelector('#output').value += '\nobj = ' + obj;
    }
}
```

Keep clicking the button you can see your values printed.

You should learn how to use a debugger, you can step through your code and see what the values are at each step.